# show that the sequence $x_n=\sqrt[n]{1+a_n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, contest-math

> Let $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers so that $1+a_{m+n}\leq (1+a_m)(1+a_n)$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ defined by $x_n=\sqrt[n]{1+a_n}$ converges.

I think one can use the monotone convergence theorem. As long as one can show that $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below or increasing and bounded above, one can conclude the desired limit exists. Obviously $x_n\ge 1$ for all n. Also the condition implies $1+a_{2n} \leq (1+a_n)^2$ and by induction $1+a_{kn}\leq (1+a_n)^k$ for all $k,n\ge 1.$ Hence $1+a_n \leq (1+a_1)^n$ (taking $n=1,k=n$) and so $x_n\leq 1+a_1$ for all n. It might be useful to come up with a particular sequence $(a_n)$ so that one can determine whether $x_n$ is actually increasing or decreasing. But I'm not sure how to come up with such a sequence. To show that $x_n\leq x_{k}$ we can show $x_n^c\leq x_k^c$ for some positive real number c or $\dfrac{x_n}{x_k}\leq 1.$ We have that $1+a_{n+1}\leq (1+a_n)(1+a_1).$ I'm also not sure how to determine which of $x_{n+1}$ or $x_n$ must be larger or equal to the other.  As a simple example, consider comparing $x_1$ and $x_2$. We have $1+a_2\leq (1+a_1)^2$ and $x_2=\sqrt{1+a_2}$ so $x_2\leq x_1$, and so as a guess I'd say $x_n$ should be decreasing.

Comment: let $x_n=\log(1+a_n)$. THe conditions of the OP imply that $x_n+x_m\geq x_{n+m}$. This is a sub additive function. It is well known that $\lim_n\frac{x_n}{n}$ converges to $\inf_m\frac{x_m}{m}$. See this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2556630/121671)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subadditive Sequence Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556630/subadditive-sequence-convergence)

Comment: You can also use that induction inequality by rooting it by $kn$ to get $x_{kn} \le x_n$, which seems useful.