# Proving sequence limit given condition weaker than monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $a_{n+m} \leq a_n + a_m$ for all $m,n \geq 1$. (So the sequence is not necessarily monotonic, but from $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$, it can increase by at most $a_1$). Let \begin{equation*}I = \inf\left\{\frac{a_n}{n}: n \geq 1\right\}\end{equation*} It is to be shown that in fact \begin{equation*}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n} = I\end{equation*}
I attempted to show that the sequence $\left(\frac{a_n}{n}\right)$ is monotonically decreasing, which would imply the result, but this in fact seems to be false in the general case. So any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This is Fekete's Subadditive Lemma and proofs are easily available.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808404/prove-lim-n-to-infty-fraca-nn-exists-for-positive-sequence-where-a-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to build the following two steps argument

First, note that for any $\epsilon$ it is always possible to find a sequence $\{ a_{N+kn} \}_{n}$ such that $\frac{a_{N+nk}}{N+nk} < I + \epsilon$. This follows by choosing $N$ and $k$ such that $a_N < NI + N \epsilon$ and $a_k < kI + k \epsilon$ and from the inequality $a_{n+m} \leq a_n + a_m$.

Then, note that for any $n$ and for $1 \leq i \leq k$ one has $a_{N+kn+i} - a_{N+kn} < i a_1$, therefore

$$
\frac{a_{N+kn+i}}{N+kn+i} \leq I + 2 \epsilon
$$

for all $i$ for any $n$ sufficiently large.