# Sequence such that $x_{n+m} \leq x_n+x_m$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I have a couple of questions about the following type of sequences :

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_n \geq  0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ and that $$x_{n+m} \leq x_n+x_m \quad \forall n,m \in \mathbb N $$

1. In order to show that the sequence $(\frac{x_n}{n})$ converges, all proofs "guess" the limit that is $\inf(\frac{x_n}{n})$ and then use Euclidean division. What if I cannot guess it by myself (which actually happened) and do not think of using Euclidean division ?
2. What happens if the sequence's property is $$x_{n+m} \geq x_n+x_m \quad \forall n,m \in \mathbb N $$
   I feel like that here the sequence $(\frac{n}{x_n})$ will converge (tried with $x_n=e^n$), but I am not really sure...

Comment: What do you mean by "all proofs". I can think of a proof that doesn't use that. Also what do you mean by "cannot guess by myself"? I mean if you can't figure out a proof you can't figure it out... sometimes you need someone else to tell you what the proof is or you have to think about it more. Also the second question is just a different question.

Comment: By "all proofs" I mean all the proofs I saw.
By "cannot guess by myself" I mean, is there a way to guess it, a hint maybe ?

Comment: Not sure if this leads to an efficient solution or not, but you can start by noticing that $x_n\le nx_1$, so $0\le \frac{x_n}{n}\le x_1$. This shows the sequence is bounded, so you have a subsequence $\left(\frac{x_{n_i}}{n_i}\right)_{i=1}^\infty$ converging to some $L$.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808404/prove-lim-n-to-infty-fraca-nn-exists-for-positive-sequence-where-a-n?noredirect=1&lq=1.