# Convergence of the sequence $ 0 \le a_{m+n} \le a_m + a_n, m,n \in \Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a problem with this excercise.

Let a sequance $(a_n) \subset \Bbb R $ meet condition:

$ 0 \le a_{m+n} \le a_m + a_n, m,n \in \Bbb N$

Show that a sequance $(\frac{a_n}{n})$ is convergent to finite limit.

So, I’ve shown that if $\frac{a_k}{k} \le \frac{a_d}{d}$, then for every natural l we have $ \frac{a_{k+dl}}{k+dl} \le \frac{a_d}{d} $.

And also if k|n then $\frac{a_n}{n} \le \frac{a_k}{k}$
The proof of those observations is just using the inequality over and over again.

And my idea was to show, that this sequance is decreasing, beacuse with the fact that everything is smaller than $\frac{a_1}{1}$ and bigger than 0, we would get that this sequance is convergent to some number between this two bounds so end of proof. And please, just give me some hints, because I want to solve it by myself :).

Comment: This question has been asked on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808404/prove-lim-n-to-infty-fraca-nn-exists-for-positive-sequence-where-a-n). Please be aware that the link contains complete answers instead of just hints. Anyway I guess someone will close this question as duplicate.

Comment: Oh, okey, thank you